# Not able to finish when using streamconverters. asoutputstream.mapMaterializedValue in PlayFramework

Tags: scala, playframework, outputstream, akka-stream

When I run:

```
def zip() = Action {
  val zipSource: Source[ByteString, _] =
    StreamConverters
      .asOutputStream()
      .mapMaterializedValue(os => Future {
         Thread.sleep(1)
         println("*********** Start")
         os.write("happy".getBytes("UTF8"))
         println("*********** Sent")
         os.close()
         println("*********** OS closed")
      })

  Status(200).sendEntity(HttpEntity.Streamed(zipSource, None, Some("application/zip")))
}
```

I get the print statement:

```
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
*********** Start
*********** Sent
*********** OS closed
```

However, the downloading process stays in "Starting" and never moves forward. I have to cancel the process. Does anyone know why?

Comment: What do you see if you use [`curl -v`](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-verbose.html) on that action?

Comment: Depends from your play version, it could be an issue in akka: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6743
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6621